# How to get progress bars work in jenkins console

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

How do i get progress bars work display correctly in jenkins console log

I am running jenkins master and slave in a docker container and my build job is getting laravel installed before testing it. But composer install looks very ugly, i am pretty sure there is a way to make it look pretty and user friendly.

i even tried ansicolor plugin but still no luck, please refer to screenshot for the issue i am having

```
node {
    stage...
    stage...
    stage('Build') {
        ansiColor('xterm') {
            sh 'composer install'
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem, and from my research it seems that it is due to the fact that Jenkins replaces all "\r" with "\n". See issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49918
This makes the printed lines to be appended to new line instead of overriding each other to show progress.
It seems it was not resolved yet.